# Adding Typescript Type Declarations to Monaco Editor

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash, monaco-editor

I have a Monaco editor which the user inputs custom javascript code. Within this Monaco Editor they can use Lodash functionality. I want to be able to give them the  intellisense / code completion for lodash, by including the type definitions.

I've seen a few answers relating to adding custom declarations, but none that are including a whole 3rd party libraries declarations. Has anybody had experience with this.

This is what I have so far. Then below I create the editor, similar to the example in the documentation.

```
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib("", "./../../types/lodash/index.d.ts");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this as an example and the apis. you should pass the content of the `.d.ts` file as the first argument

`monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(content, "")`

check [this](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-javascript-defaults) demo of how pass arguments

Comment: Ahh...okay so basically I need to make some sort of AJAX call for the contents of this file, then feed it into the content variable, I can't just pass the file path? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to add the package [monaco-editor-auto-typings](https://github.com/lukasbach/monaco-editor-auto-typings/) as an option. Disclaimer: I'm the developer of that package.

It continuously scans code entered in the monaco editor, detects imports and automatically loads the declaration files from UnPkg.

```
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';
import { AutoTypings, LocalStorageCache } from 'monaco-editor-auto-typings';

const val = `
import React from 'react';
React.useEffect(0); // Type Error!
`;

// Create monaco editor instance
const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('root')!, {
  model: monaco.editor.createModel(val, 'typescript'),
});

// Initialize auto typing on monaco editor. Imports will now automatically be typed!
const autoTypings = AutoTypings.create(editor, {
  sourceCache: new LocalStorageCache(), // Cache loaded sources in localStorage. May be omitted
  // Other options...
});
```

You can explore how it works in the [demo](https://lukasbach.github.io/monaco-editor-auto-typings/).

Answer (score 7):

*(Copied from my GH Gist: https://gist.github.com/cdrini/9de507f6ac19da30fd27c5f618783b31 )*

Well that was a headache! This is certainly not an elegant solution, but it works. Hopefully someone can use these notes to save themselves a bunch of time.

Known issues:

- This does not scale easily to any other library
- Requires some internal knowledge of lodash's types library which might break on a lodash update

#### Add `raw-loader` and `@types/lodash`

```sh
npm install --save-dev @types/lodash raw-loader
```

(as of writing, these are at 4.14.162 and 4.0.2, respectively)

#### Import and register the .d.ts files

Looking at [@types/lodash/index.d.ts](https://unpkg.com/browse/@types/lodash@4.14.162/index.d.ts), copy all the `common` references and import them. :

```js
import LODASH_index from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/index.d.ts';
import LODASH_common from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts';
import LODASH_array from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts';
import LODASH_collection from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/collection.d.ts';
import LODASH_date from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/date.d.ts';
import LODASH_function from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts';
import LODASH_lang from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/lang.d.ts';
import LODASH_math from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/math.d.ts';
import LODASH_number from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/number.d.ts';
import LODASH_object from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts';
import LODASH_seq from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/seq.d.ts';
import LODASH_string from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/string.d.ts';
import LODASH_util from '!raw-loader!@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts';
```

- Note: Vetur will complain in VS Code about importing `.d.ts` files, but won't error.

Then register them into monaco (wherever monaco is in your project):

```js
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_index, '@types/lodash/index.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_common, '@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_array, '@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_collection, '@types/lodash/common/collection.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_date, '@types/lodash/common/date.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_function, '@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_lang, '@types/lodash/common/lang.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_math, '@types/lodash/common/math.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_number, '@types/lodash/common/number.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_object, '@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_seq, '@types/lodash/common/seq.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_string, '@types/lodash/common/string.d.ts');
window.monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(LODASH_util, '@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts');
```

Note:

- The file names matter here (somehow); removing the `.d.ts` extension causes them to break.

### References/External Links

- The (largely useless) docs: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.typescript.languageservicedefaults.html#addextralib
- GH Issues:

  - [#758: monaco-typescript not picking up configured modules from addExtraLib](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/758)
  - [#754: Cannot require contents of '.d.ts' files as string in browser for addExtraLib method](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/754)
- StackOverflow Questions:

  - [Adding Typescript Type Declarations to Monaco Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290727/adding-typescript-type-declarations-to-monaco-editor)
- Monaco demo using `addExtraLib`: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-javascript-defaults
- @types/lodash at unpkg, if you want to see the .d.ts files directly: https://unpkg.com/browse/@types/lodash@4.14.162/
- GH Search for uses of `addExtraLib`: https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=addExtraLib&type=Code

### Open Questions

- What does the filename actually do? Also, what are the protocol prefixes for?